# How to prevent subclass deriving from framework base class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Writing MVC application and found this technique to be useful:
http://forums.asp.net/post/4960505.aspx
which basically puts a class-in-the-middle that overrides an event handler method for execution when any correctly derived Controller subclass Action is requested.

Is there a way I can force all not yet written Controllers in the project/solution to derive from the intended subclass-in-the-middle and/or to not be able to derive from the framework base class?

Comment: If you don't care about design time compiling, you can write your own controllerfactory that will only create controllers based on your base type.  Meaning that controllers from the base type will be derived but won't work.

Comment: thanks, after a day of thought about it, I think I was hoping for a kind of compiler/build option.  another solution might be to create a wrapper project for the system.web.mvc namespace and reference that instead of the original framework namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a custom base type for every controller, could you accomplish your goal by using a Global ActionFilter?

Examples:

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/25/conditional-filters.aspx

Comment: thanks, tremendously, that is really what I was looking for and wouldn't ever have known to ask for by the 'Filter' term at all.  I should probly get a book on MVC already